# Can't upload React Native app to iTunes Connect with Xcode 7.3

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, xcode, reactjs

I made an app using React-Native for iOS and I can't publish it to the App Store. When I go to the Xcode Organizer and follow the steps to upload the Archive, it throws the following error when `Sending API usage to iTunes Connect`.

[image: iTunes Error]

Yesterday, I tried validating and uploading other apps made with Swift and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution** found setting the minimum required version of iOS to 8.1.

It supposed to be a launch-screen-related error.

> **NOTE:** This solution also applies for Xcode 8.